# code: itemNotFound error for MS Graph API for excel createSession, I am able to get Item Id using sharedWithMe API call

Tags: excel, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am able to get Excel file info using below call

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe`

[sharedWithMe call screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdajY.png)

But when I get Item id from above call and use it to create excel session it does give me below error:

API call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{ID here}/workbook/createSession`

Error:

```
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The resource could not be found.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-02-17T06:18:19",
            "request-id": "07639ad5-08e4-4973-9804-eb805a8bce8d",
            "client-request-id": "326609a7-95dc-b36f-8db0-3b7ab2101860"
        }
```

[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pks2f.png)

**Please note: I have granted Sites.ReadWriteAll and Files.ReadWriteAll permissions.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the shared file is stored on a different drive than yours.

First, you need to get the correct drive id for the file.

When you call

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe
```

The response should contain `remoteItem` node with `parentReference` child node.

```
"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
"createdDateTime": "2021-01-05T09:51:23Z",
"id": "01BDYTYLL573DF4J3A2JG3WPFKMZLLBPQD",
...
"remoteItem": {
    "id": "01BDYTYLL573DF4J3A2JG3WPFKMZLLBPQD",
    "parentReference": {
        "driveId": "b!RdjejBSERkqd6KyrlECzSlClLPMHvAxIle01z5BIuc0OlAR_j4bQQ5j8LT1dXapM",
        "driveType": "business",
        "id": "01BDYTYLN6Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ"
    },
....
```

Use the `driveId` and item's `id` and call this endpoint to create excel session.

```
POST: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{id}/workbook/createSession
```

If you have privileges to edit the shared file then the call should succeed